# jquery-validation plug-in - error remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin for my file chooser input validation . 
I am referring the basic example given in the page.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/file_input.html

Here , If you choose a wrong  type of file then error will be shown after the file chooser component.
After this , if you choose the correct type of file the error message is not cleared immediately.
Once you do right click or do click any other component then the error message is getting removed.
Please let me know how to remove the error message as soon as the error is corrected by the user.
This is not only with File chooser component. This happens with most of the components.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps fill out a bug report to let the developer know:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Comment: Thanks Sparky . This is known issue with this plugin?

Comment: I have no idea if this is a known issue.  However, it's not behaving as you desire or expect, nor is it behaving like the other input elements, so the developer should be notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to validate the element by calling valid function on change event.

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).valid();
});
```

Working fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/twtrdb34/